# How to get performance details in virtual machine?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox, load-testing

I have virtual box in which i installed Ubuntu server 12.4. Now i am doing load testing on this virtual machine by sending number of requests. Now i want to get performance details of that virtual machine. In Ubuntu server there is no any gui installed.

Comment: Which requests, to which application, which performance, measured in what, who, where, whyyyy? Please give details, otherwise it's not a question.

Comment: And no. VMs are not made for load testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we are using python then using **paramiko library** for ssh we can get machine details by ssh of remote **vm(Virtual Machine)** and then by executing any terminal command like **top** which will give all core cpu info. That is solution that i'm using for getting CPU info.